# Windows 8 GridView multi selected items

Tags: silverlight, xaml, gridview, windows-8

I am developing an application for Windows 8, I would like to select multiple items in a GridView (by c# code), I tried this:

1st

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
{ 
    this.ItemGridView.SelectedIndex = i;
}

//in this way is only selects the third element
```

2nd

```
this.ItemGridView.SelectedItem = listPeople;

//in this way does not select anything
```

3rd

```
foreach (Persona persona in listaPersone)
{
    this.ItemGridView.SelectedItem = person;
}

//in this way is selected only the last
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this

Assume the 'listPeople' is collection what you want to select.

```
foreach(var p in listPeople)
{
    this.ItemGridView.SelectedItem.Add(p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try for Win8 but something like this should work:

```
this.ItemGridView.MultiSelect = true;

foreach (GridViewRow row in this.ItemGridView.Rows)
{
    row.Selected = selection.Contains(row.Cells[0].Value);
}
```